# Ratio of listener threads to worker threads in UDP/TCP server?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, networking

I'm writing a server that handles both UDP and TCP connections, and have written a basic threadpool library that underlies the server. I have a listener thread that does the accept/recvfrom syscalls (for TCP and UDP respectively) and pushes tasks to the threadpool, but I don't think having one listener thread for n worker threads will perform well as n increases past 50 or 60 threads. For example, if I have an instantiated UDP server with 60 worker threads and a listener thread that does recvfrom. If the processor needs to context switch among all these threads, my concern is that -

1. The listener thread will spend more time unscheduled, and so will drop more packets than is acceptable
2. Since only 1 thread is listening, most worker threads will have no task to perform and so will spend most of their time sleeping

What is the ratio between listeners and workers? How could I determine this ratio?

Comment: _"What is the ratio between listeners and workers?"_ Sorry there's no ready made formula. It totally depends on your actual use case, deployment and requirements.

Comment: Amended my question. I figured there wasn't a formula. I have no idea how to determine this ratio, however.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "listener thread"?  A thread that calls `accept()` to listen for incoming connections?  Or a thread that listens for data from an already-connected client?

Comment: The former, in the case of TCP, and for UDP the listener calls recvfrom and pushes the resulting data to a threadpool

Comment: One hack is simply to have the listen thread run at a higher scheduler priority than the consumers, so it always preempts them

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is a variant of the [Thundering Herd Problem](https://lkml.org/lkml/2004/5/2/108). For larger numbers of connections, the N:N model (one worker per request) does start to break down because of context switches. What many applications do instead is have an M:N model, where M is the number of requests and N is the number of CPUs. Approximately N worker threads are started to handle the requests, and depending on how much CPU vs I/O work the threads do and the other processes running on the system the number of worker threads can be increased above N or below N respectively.

One very good scheduler implementation for high CPU work processes is the [scheduler in TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/task_scheduler.htm). It also takes into account cache affinity. It's worth looking at even if just for ideas.

Comment: Another outstanding toolset to consider is the [IOCP facilities of Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). They take a fair amount of work and understanding to set up properly, but once done, they have the *enormous* advantages in kernel-level blocking detection and thread resource management. Invoking a blocking call on nearly any IO api puts the current thread in a running-but-waiting state that pushes the IOCP pool manager to release another thread against the current pending workload. Worth looking at if Windows is the target platform.